# DataGridViewComboBoxCell not updating list item

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I'm trying to update values in a combobox in my datagridview.  Sounds simple enough right.

I have several pre-existing rows added into my DGV where 2 columns are dropdown lists.
Code snippet as below, but the list is never updated visually with the new category.
This method works for other stand alone combo boxes, but not for the ones in the datagridview.

```
// List<string> _mCategories
_mCategories.Add("new category");
_mCategories.Sort();

for(int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell c1 = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4] as 
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

    c1.Items.Clear();
    c1.Items.AddRange(_mCategory.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Data binding would massively reduce this headache

Comment: I've never really used databinding before.  I looked into it and works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I should have given some more info on this than just a a scrappy comment

In a data binding scenario I would:

- Create a new dataset
- Add a table to it to hold all the data you want to show in the grid - example Address. Add tow int columns to it for a lookup, e.g. AddressType where 1 will be Work and 2 will be Home, and BuildingType where 1 will be "Apartment Block" etc...
- Add two more tables with two columns each - one column holds the text string to show in the combobox lists (e.g. "Apartment Block" in the building type combo or "Home" in the address type combo), the other column holds the number (1) you want to store in the main table. I tend to call these columns Disp and Val because the DisplayMember property of the combo will be set to the text Disp column and the combo's ValueMember will be set to Val.
- Save the dataset
- Open the data sources window in VS
- Expand the dataset node, drag the node representing the main table (Address), onto the form
- A datagridview appears and it is databound to the new dataset instance via the binding source (these components appear at the bottom of the form designer - see the somedataSet, and the addressBindingSource)
- Edit the columns of the grid, change the AddressType column to be a datagridviewcombobox type

  - Set it's `DataSource` to be the table that holds the display/value pairs for the combo e.g. Other >> Project Data Sources >> DataSetName >> AddressType
  - Set the `DisplayMember` of the combo to be the string column (Disp)
  - Set the `ValueMember` of the combo to be the int column (Val)
  - Check that the `DataPropertyName` property is referencing the name of the column in the main grid that holds the addresstype (AddressType)

That should be it. Your combo will consult the dataset.AddressType table to get the list it shows, it will show the contents of Disp, and it will use the value it finds in Val to poke into the Address.AddressType or Address.BuildingType columns (depending which combo it is)

Add some data to your main table (don't add data to the grid; add it directly to the datatable the grid is bound to) and add a load of addresstypes/buildingtypes to the smaller tables

Now if your main table has a 1 in its addresstype column, the combo will show "work". If you change it to "home" the main table row will be updated to 2

I followed the steps here in a video and recorded it. At one point you'll see me drop a button on the form. That's just so I can have something to click that will hit a breakpoint then I can inspect the contents of the dataset and show you how it goes

https://youtu.be/EuHrIE3-BoE